# How can I capture an image using react-native-camera package getting Nosuitable image URL loaded found for null

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I use rn-camera to capture pictures alone. But after updating it not working fine and getting  Nosuitable image URL loaded found for null. Can anyone suggest me any solution for this? My code is below

```
       <View>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam
          }}
          style={styles.view}
         // aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
          >
        </Camera>
      </View>
        <Icon style = {{ alignSelf:'center' }}onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} name="camera" size={50}/>
  </View>

  takePicture() {
    const options = {}
    this.camera.takePictureAsync({metadata: options}).then((data) => {
        ImagePicker.openCropper({
          path: data.path,
          width: deviceWidth,
          height: deviceWidth*5/4,
          cropperToolbarTitle: '',
          hideBottomControls: true,
          enableRotationGesture: true
        }).then(image => {
          this.props.screenProps.navigation.navigate(this.props.screenProps.navigation.state.params.screenName, {uri: image.path})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("openCropper error = " + err)
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `data.uri`, the `imagePicker` takes uri which has all the details you need to work a cropper, or you can use  "react-native-image-crop-picker" also.

```
ImagePicker.openCropper({
              path: data.path, // Add the data.uri here 
              width: deviceWidth,
              height: deviceWidth*5/4,
              cropperToolbarTitle: '',
              hideBottomControls: true,
              enableRotationGesture: true
            }).then(image => {
              this.props.screenProps.navigation.navigate(this.props.screenProps.navigation.state.params.screenName, {uri: image.path})
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log("openCropper error = " + err)
            });
```